# Rendering issues with zip extracted images in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, rendering

I am trying to make the user upload a zip file then extract only the image files inside the zip folder and then render them on the screen. However the rendering/re-rendering only happens when the code recompiles(i usually change a letter inside an html descriptor to do this) The regex part is gpt generated. The useEffect hook logs an empty array after the upload button is clicked but after a recompile it prints the full array. I couldnt find an answer anywhere else as this is some unusual behaviour by React.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import JSZip from 'jszip';

const ImageUploader = () => {
  const [selectedZipFile, setSelectedZipFile] = useState(null);
  const [extractedImages, setExtractedImages] = useState([]);
  const [change, setChange] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (extractedImages.length > 0) {
      console.log(extractedImages);
      // Trigger re-render when extractedImages state updates
      setChange(c=>c+1);
    }
  }, [extractedImages]); // Run this effect whenever extractedImages state changes

  const handleZipChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedZipFile(file);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    if (!selectedZipFile) return;

    try {
      const zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(selectedZipFile);
      const imageFiles = [];

      zip.forEach(async (relativePath, zipEntry) => {
        if (zipEntry.dir || !zipEntry.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)) return; // Skip directories and non-image files
        const blob = await zipEntry.async("blob");
        const dataUrl = await readBlobAsDataURL(blob);
        imageFiles.push({ name: zipEntry.name, dataUrl });
      });

      setExtractedImages(imageFiles); // Update extractedImages state

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error extracting images from zip file:', error);
    }
  };

  const readBlobAsDataURL = (blob) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Image Uploader</h2>
      <input type="file" accept=".zip" onChange={handleZipChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload} disabled={!selectedZipFile}>Upload Zip</button>
      {change > 0 && extractedImages.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h3>Extracted Images:</h3>
          {extractedImages.map((image, index) => (
            <img key={index} src={image.dataUrl} alt={image.name} style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageUploader;
```

Comment: One problem is the use of forEach with async in handleUpload.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop